# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '<package>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and I am writing an integration test class.
When I run my test class, I get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.whot.dao.HotspotDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
```

I have searched for a while and looked for clues as to what might be causing this but I have not been able to come up with the reason this happens. Help would be appreciated. I have included some details of my code.

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${psql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I have this in my Application.Java class

```
package com.whot;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whot.controller"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.whot.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.whot.repository", "com.whot.dao"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and in my integration class

```
package com.whot.dao;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class HotspotDaoIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private HotspotDao hotspotDao;

    @Autowired
    private  TestEntityManager entityManager;

    private  String hotspotName = "Mavericks";


    @Test
    public void givenHotspotNameReturnHotspotSuccessfully(){
        Address address = new Address("Allen Mgba Crescent", 30L);
        entityManager.persist(address);

        Hotspot hotspot = new Hotspot(hotspotName);
        entityManager.persist(hotspot);
        entityManager.flush();

        HotspotLocation hsLocation = new HotspotLocation(address);
        hsLocation.setHotspotId(hotspot.getId());
        entityManager.persist(hsLocation);
        hotspot.getHotspotLocations().add(hsLocation);

        HotspotDTO hotspotDto =((ArrayList<HotspotDTO>) hotspotDao.getHotspotByName(hotspotName)).get(0);
        assertEquals(hotspotDto.getId(), hotspot.getId());
        assertEquals(hotspotDto.getName(), hotspot.getName());
    }
}
```

and the class in question here

```
package com.whot.dao;


@Component
public class HotspotDao {

    @Autowired
    HotspotRespository hsRepository;

    public Collection<HotspotDTO> getHotspotByName(String hotspotName) {
       Collection <HotspotDTO> hotspots = getHotspotsByName(Arrays.asList(hotspotName));
       return hotspots;
    }

    public Collection<HotspotDTO> getHotspotsByName(Collection <String> names) {
        Collection<Hotspot> hotspots =  hsRepository.findHotspotsByName(names);
        Collection<HotspotDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Hotspot hotspot: hotspots){
            result.add(new HotspotDTO().toHotspotDto(hotspot));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The class `HotspotDao` is in package `com.whot.dao`, which is not under component scan (`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whot.controller"})`).

Comment: @manish That is basically an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot default scan will start the same package and subpackers with startup application class.

If the other annotation is not in the same package, it will not be able to scan, the solution is to use the @ComponentScan annotation on startup application class, declare the package scan path. like...

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.exp.package1","com.exp.package2"})
```